# Cent/OS Virtual Machine Hostname not accessable but IP is

Tags: linux, windows, apache, networking, virtual-machine

I have 2 virtual machines one windows 7 and one Cent/OS 6. 
Both are running in VM Fusion and both function fine. Both Machines are running apache.
The Windows machine is running UWAMP 
The Cent machine is running standard apache (Httpd).

The machine name of the windows VM is "Win-Server-Apache1" and when I ping it from another machine on the network the machine name resolves to whatever it's IP is. (192.168.1.xx).

The Cent machine however I can't ping by entering a machine name, even though I've changed it's hostname to be "Linux-Server-Apache1" I can however ping it's IP address (192.168.1.xx).

I know both machines are working because I can bring up the info.php on both machines, however the linux machine can ONLY be reached via it's IP and not via it's host/machine name.

I have checked and disabled all firewalls on both the VM's and the Host OS so I know it's not an issue with firewalls. Both machines are running webservers and both can be reached in a browser on the same network.. only the linux machine I have to use the IP. I would prefer to use machine/hostnames if possible.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: just because you change a host's name doesn't mean you can magically use that name on the network. the machine you're running the ping from needs to know about that name. either via a HOSTS file entry, or DNS lookups. Regardless, offtopic for this site. Not a programming question, so voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ether:

1. Add to your DNS new hosts
2. Allow DHCP to update DNS
3. Edit /etc/hosts with IPs and hostnames of other hosts.

You don't need to disable firewalls for name resolution to work (well, you need to connect to the DNS server!)